# Depth First Search with Adjacency Matrix

Tags: c++, adjacency-matrix

I am completing a class lab which takes an adjacency matrix, and determines connectivity among vertices. Although my code runs, it does not give the correct results.

I believe there is a problem with the the second if statement in my while loop. any help is greatly appreciated. Code is below:

```
#include "graph.h"
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

bool Graph::connected(int v,int w) {

    int visited[SIZE] ={0};

    if (v == w)         
        return adj_matrix[v][v];

    Queue<int> Q;      
    Q.Enqueue(v);      

    while (!Q.empty()) {
        int curr = Q.Dequeue();

        if (curr == w)
            return true;

        int z=0;         
        for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {      
            if (adj_matrix[curr][z]==1 && visited[i]==false) {
                Q.Enqueue(z);
                visited[i]==true;
            }   
        }
    }
    return false;  
}
```

This is the output I am receiving:

```
0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 
vertex 0 is connected to vertices: 
vertex 1 is connected to vertices: 
vertex 2 is connected to vertices: 
vertex 3 is connected to vertices: 3
```

Which is clearly missing another connection between 0 and 2 correct?

Comment: One thing to also note, using a regular queue scheme like you have implements a bredth-first-search. You need to push on the front of the queue each unvisited element to implement a depth first search (just a little side note, not that it matters for determining connectivity). But you aren't incrementing z. z should be incremented up to z as well. Maybe another loop inside the for(int i) loop.

Comment: Hi Pippin, I totally mislabeled the post...it was indeed a breadth first search we were assigned. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at your use of the variables i and z.  It appears that z is assigned the value 0, and never changed after that.  You may want to try using more descriptive variable names to avoid this sort of confusion.

Comment: Once I changed visited[i]==false to visited[z]==false the program ran. If I understand correctly Z represents all the vertices adjacent to curr(current node) which needed to be visited. Once I declared Z had not yet been visited, I guess it fixed it...

Comment: I'm not sure if you've given the full description of your change, but based on what you just said, z will still always have a value of 0!

Answer (score 1):

Also see that :

Q.Enqueue(z);
visited[i]==true; (its having two "=") its wrong.

Change it to

Q.Enqueue(z);
visited[i]=true;

And renmove the z altogether and use only i.

hey one more point:  Do you want to implement 'Depth First", then why are you using Queue. Depth first uses stack. Please check once again, what you want to implement. Though for connectivity, both can be used.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As per the lab, we were to use a queue to schedule the vertex visits. I managed to get it running correctly and actually kept the items I had. I needed to swap the last two lines of  the last if statement. I put z in the queue last. I also adjusted visited[i]==false in my if statement to visited[z]...Thanks much

Comment: Oh, we were also instructed to perform BFS...Thanks!